# Pgfmath array problem

Tags: arrays, pgfmath

I have a problem with pgfmath array :

- it work if defined outside pgfkeys,
- doesn't work inside.

What is the problem ?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{tag/.style={align=center}}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/DiagCirc/.cd,
    value list/.store in=\Value@list,
    tags/.store in=\T@gs,
    tags=,
    percent corr/.store in=\C@rrP,
    percent corr=,
    diagram/.code={%
    % Calcul de la somme
    \pgfmathsetmacro\S@m{0}
    \foreach \i/\y in \Value@list {\xdef\S@m{\S@m+\i}}  
    \pgfmathsetmacro\S@m{\S@m}

    \ifx\hfuzz\T@gs\hfuzz
    \else
        \foreach \V/\N [count=\j from 0] in \Value@list {%

        % works
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\P{round(\V/\S@m*100)+\CorrP[\j]}

        % doesn't work
        %\pgfmathtruncatemacro\P{round(\V/\S@m*100)+\C@rrP[\j]}

        \node[tag] at (\j,0) {\T@gs} ;
        }
    \fi%

    } % fin du diagram code
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\CorrP{{-1,0,0,0,0}}

\path[/DiagCirc/.cd,
value list={1236/R+L+D,149/A,740/N+F,346/C,75/E},
percent corr={{-1,0,0,0,0}},
tags=\P\,\%,
diagram] ;


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ` \pgfmathparse{array({\C@rrP},\j)}
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro\P{\P+\pgfmathresult} 
` does the right thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the braces of the array in a key is stripped off. Instead you can make it a double braced array before the loop then it is still understood as a valid PGF array.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{tag/.style={align=center}}
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/DiagCirc/.cd,
    value list/.store in=\Value@list,
    tags/.store in=\T@gs,
    tags=,
    percent corr/.store in=\C@rrP,
    percent corr=,
    diagram/.code={%
    % Calcul de la somme
    \pgfmathsetmacro\S@m{0}%
    \foreach \i/\y in \Value@list {\xdef\S@m{\S@m+\i}}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\S@m{\S@m}%
    \ifx\hfuzz\T@gs\hfuzz%
    \else%
        \expandafter\def\expandafter\C@rrP\expandafter{\expandafter{\C@rrP}}%
        \foreach \V/\N [count=\j from 0] in \Value@list {%
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\P{round(\V/\S@m*100)+\C@rrP[\j]}%
            \node[tag] at (\j,0) {\T@gs};%
        }%
    \fi%
    } % fin du diagram code
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[/DiagCirc/.cd,
value list={1236/R+L+D,149/A,740/N+F,346/C,75/E},
percent corr={-1,0,0,0,0},
tags=\P\,\%,
diagram];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]